# Views exposed filter - Replace '-Any-' by Select All

Tags: views, charts

I have a view with an exposed filter of taxonomy terms. Because I'm using [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), when I select the option '-Any-', the chart gets messed up. I noticed that, if I select all terms available instead of '-Any-', the chart looks ok.

So my question is, it is possible to replace the '-Any-' with a select all or, in some way, force the any to select all?

Comment: Updated the link to charts module.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered. Please find the answer in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975294/5093173

or use this code

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'view name') {
      $form['filter_name']['#options']['All'] = t('select all');
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, but that solution is to change the label. What I need is to select all terms in the exposed filter when I select all - this can be done in any way, I just need that functionality.